# Firebase functions: storage cannot be stubbed when writing unit tests

Tags: firebase, mocha.js, firebase-storage, sinon, google-cloud-functions

I have the following functions code inside index.js:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
admin.storage();
```

And the following test code:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var sinon = require('sinon');
describe('Event Sourcing', function() {
  var myFunctions, adminInitStub, adminStorageStub,admin;

  before(() => {
    admin =  require('firebase-admin');
    adminStorageStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'storage');
    adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');

    myFunctions = require('../index');
  });

  after(() => {
    // Restoring our stubs to the original methods.
    adminInitStub.restore();
    adminStorageStub.restore();
  });

  describe('CREATED', function() {
      it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
            assert.equal(-1, [1,5,3].indexOf(4));
          });
    });
});
```

For some strange reason, I keep getting the following error `Error: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.` but I've clearly stubbed it. Why does stubbing work for initializeApp() but not storage().

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`admin.storage()` is actually a getter and therefore needs to be stubbed this way

```
adminStorageStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'storage').get(() => {
  return () => {
    return {bucket: (() => {})};
  }
});
```

More info on sinon stubs can be found here http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.0.0/stubs/

Comment: Thanks! I spent a lot of time on this, I was getting node FStat errors, and I could NOT figure this out on my own for another 2 days maybe.